# Axis2 : Why two response (one ending with E) classes are being generated with axis2 wsdl2java

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

This is my Java Code for the webservice interface  developed using Apache Axis2:

```
public String Distrategy(@WebParam(name = "request") Request request) ;
```

And also i have the implementation class for this

```
public String Distrategy(@WebParam(name = "request") Request request) 
{
return "Ex";
}
```

I have deployed this into the server and also Tomcat has generated a WSDL File for this .

Now , i need to write a client for this wsdl , so when i used wsdl2java option .
Surprisingly , it generated two Response classes

1. DistrategyResponse
2. DistrategyResponseE

And on to the wsdl file  DistrategyResponse  is present ,but there is nothing like DistrategyResponseE

Could anybody please let me know what is this DistrategyResponseE ??

Thank you very much .